# Paypal HTML integration problems (sales tax not showing for recurring payment)

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-sandbox

I am using the Paypal standard (HTML 'API') to integrate Paypal to my website.

I have managed to display 'subscribe' buttons for recurring payments, using HTML variables as specified in the Paypal documentation. However, there is one serious "show stopper" problem:

I am unable to get Paypal to recognize sales tax amount for RECURRING PAYMENTS.

Despite using the 'tax' field (and setting a positive number to it), the tax is not being displayed on the bill for the recurring item.

Using the 'tax' field for a 'buy now' button does however work correctly (the tax amount is shown on the bill page). Has anyone else experienced this - and what is the solution (or work around for this?)

BTW, I am running in the Paypal sandbox

Answer (score 3):

Presently sales tax not supported for PayPal subscription buttons.  It has been submitted as a requested feature.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.x.com/message/192506) thread on their forums. There's a comment from Dec 2010 that states that _..I do not know if this will be something that is updated nor when this will be available.._. The thread was started in 2008. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am just looking at the PayPal Subscriptions and have just realise this as a possible issue. As a work-around, the subscription amount could just be the total subscription amount including any taxes. An invoice with the breakdown of taxes will just need to be issues outside of PayPal.