# paypal subscriptions and tax

Tags: paypal

I am using the Paypal HTML API for a website. Paypal seems to be ignoring the tax field, for recurring payments.

Is this a bug? (I know it was a while back). Has anyone managed to add tax calculations to Paypal recurring payments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not supported.

See [Paypal HTML integration problems (sales tax not showing for recurring payment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620071/paypal-html-integration-problems-sales-tax-not-showing-for-recurring-payment) -- it's an old question (that's incidentally displayed in the list to the right of your question; please search before asking!) but has a comment from less than a month ago that is still relevant.

It in turn links to [an official thread](https://www.x.com/message/192506) that's years old, updated just a few months ago with:

> I apologize for the misguided
>   information that you received
>   previously through phone support. 
>   Feature requests have been submitted
>   up on this to see if this is something
>   that can be added into a future
>   release.  However, I do not know if
>   this will be something that is updated
>   nor when this will be available.   The
>   only work around at this time, is to
>   include all tax and shipping charges
>   into the subscription amount.

Comment: "an official link" does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Today I had a two hours call with Paypal reps - they themselves were surprised to find our that it doesn't add the VAT to recurring payments, and indeed it doesn't.

The reason, most probably is that the VAT % can be changed over the period of the subscription, and once the user committed to pay certain amount, they can't change it over time. Very silly - but still - they don't have that option. May be due to legal reasons.